# How to import new policy definition or ADMX files to AWS managed Active directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, group-policy

I am trying to import Google Chrome policy definition (ADMX) files to setup group policy for Google Chrome installed on the windows EC2 instances connected to AD domain.

I don't seem to find a solution to import new admx file in aws managed AD.

Usually it requires copying the files to domain controller's server.
But aws does not provide access to the server for managed AD.

So is there any way I can import admx file to AWS managed AD? or any other alternative to enforce Google Chrome policies?

Answer (score 1):

•   In an AWS managed active directory, AWS disallows operations by customers that would interfere with managing the service which also includes accessing the directory service from powershell or performing any low-level administrative AD task that requires administrative privileges. Also, directory service administration is handled using an Admin account rather than the usual Administrator account. Both measures are related to the way in which AWS restricts low-level access to the Directory Service due to which even accessing the group policy management console and editing or creating a new group policy is restricted task in this instance of AWS managed active directory.

•   But even though the above stated is true, you can try as a workaround to import the google chrome group policy templates in your active directory. For this, you will need an amazon EC2 instance with Windows Server installed in it, join to AWS managed AD as well as workspaces directory and extract the google chrome ADMX policy templates in a folder in C:\ drive.

•   Once done, navigate the domain’s network shared folder with organization’s FQDN, i.e., ‘\abc.com’ by going to the Windows File explorer  Network  FQDN. Open the ‘SYSVOL’ folder, then FQDN  Policies. If the folder doesn’t exist, create a folder named ‘Policy definitions’, then copy the google chrome ‘.admx’ template file in the ‘PolicyDefinitions’ folder. Then open the en-US folder and copy the ‘.adml’ template file in this folder. Thus, in this way, you can try importing the google chrome policy templates in AWS managed AD.

•   To verify the same, you can open the group policy management console tool on the amazon EC2 instance that is joined to the workspaces directory and check the group policy objects accordingly in ‘ForestDomainFQDNGroup Policy ObjectsDefault Domain PolicyEditComputer ConfigurationPoliciesAdministrative TemplatesGoogle chrome’

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/access-workspaces-with-access-cards/install-the-group-policy-administrative-template-files-for-the-workspaces-streaming-protocol-wsp.html

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwindows